# import csv with empty title or description in Prestashop

Tags: csv, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a csv file with over 10,000 products but when i try to import i get the below error

```
Property Product->description is not valid
Property Product->name is not valid
```

So when i checked those products in the csv, they dont have a description or title. Since there are over 10000 products its very difficult to sort the ones with the title or description.

So is there away to import the file even the fields are empty? Im using Prestashop 1.7

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I also get the same error, for the `description` and `summary` I'm importing html, not sure if that's possible or how. I see tutorial videos that show that it's possible to use html in the description.

I think `name` is really required, and can't be empty, because it generates the urls if I'm correct. I think description can be empty, not sure. Maybe you can use a category name and reference ID/SKU as a name?

Answer (score 0):

this post is still popular for somebody. that's why I want to reply it.

so, this problem occurs when the import file's structure is not correct for P.S

there is a strange stiation for export/import on Prestashop side. Today I export categories from 1.7.8.7 and try to import on another store which is same P.S version. But I faced the same error.

Then, I downloaded the sample import data from P.S Admin, relasided that the **structure was different** (exported csv vs example-import csv file).

- To download example CSV file, see here: https://prnt.sc/ieZIAsXOkH8y
- To understand the differences, see here: https://prnt.sc/MAyd5weCvvNX

So, I replaced the structure like example-import csv, finally it worked!

The point is being sure about your import file's structre is same with the Prestashop expectation.

Note that the error is same but my example is for category.